# Heroku worker crashing immediately

Tags: python, heroku

I deployed a python worker in Heroku cloud with an app. My Procfile is as follows.

```
worker: python worker.py
```

Worker will read a text file, do some changes and writes to another text file. Both text files are in app root directory. This is happening line by line. Approximately, this will take around 6hrs. But once I deploy it, within 1min or so it will crash.  Error is logged as

```
State changed from up to crashed
Process exited with status 0
```

I have no clue what is causing this.

Comment: `Process exited with status 0` usually means that the script finished running successfully. Can you post the contents of `worker.py` somewhere and link to it?